# Content Search, Rebuild Index error

Tags: c#, solr, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I am new to Sitecore and got a task to build the search using SiteCore 7 API. getting following error on search result query execution.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
fieldNameTranslator
```

error raised from following line

```
IQueryable<SearchResultItem> results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>();
```

stack says

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrIndexParameters..ctor(IIndexValueFormatter valueFormatter, IFieldQueryTranslatorMap`1 fieldQueryTranslators, FieldNameTranslator fieldNameTranslator, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts) +284
```

I have logged on to content management system and in Index Manager I am trying to rebuild index of sitecore_web_index but I get following error

```
Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_web_index|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Sitecore.Exceptions.ProviderConfigurationException: Solr operations unavailable. Please check your global.asax,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Check whether you can access Solr from a machine that hosts Sitecore app.
- Make sure that `ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress` setting points to a right Solr resource
- If your solution uses IoC, make sure that there is only one instance of IoC container defined for your application. If needed move container initialization to `Application_Start` method.

Comment: I can access solr using "http://localhost:8983/solr", I can see "Collection1" and "itembuckets" in the dropdown, in configuration file servicebaseaddress is already configued to use the correct and default solr url, global.asx file has following entry "<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application" %>"

Comment: But WHEN I Run Indexing of database I Get Following error Job started:. Index_Update_IndexName = Sitecore_core_index | # Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception HAS Been thrown by the target of an Invocation ---> Sitecore.Exceptions.PiaruobuiaiderConfigurationException: Solr Operations unavailable. Please check your global.asax, settings and include files.

Comment: I just disabled "Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Indexes.config" and everything is working.

Comment: When you put mentioned Solr config into /Include folder, have you disabled all Lucene configs that start with `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene`?
Also double check that you use proper versions of `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.dll` and `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider._<IoCIntegration>_.dll`.

Comment: somehow both Lucene and Solr were configured but When I marked SOLR config disabled things started working.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue the IOC is also configured on application_start but I dig into the issue further and found that the **Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchManager** class hits the **Factory.CreateObject("contentSearch/configuration", true);** method which returns **Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchConfiguration** object. But the expected object is of **ProviderIndexSearchConfiguration**. I have used the same **Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Indexes.config** which is provided in solr configuration package.

and because of that the Initialize method of Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrContentSearchManager throwing exception for Operations.

`public static void Initialize()
{
  foreach (ISearchIndex searchIndex in SolrContentSearchManager.Indexes)
  searchIndex.Initialize(); //The searchIndex.Operations is throwing above exception when I put watch on that.
}`

Answer (score 0):

- Please make sure that your schema.xml contains, `<types></types>` node which should hold `<filedtype>` node as its child. And the `<fields></fields>` node which should hold `<field>` node as its child.
- The schema.xml in Solr example folder might not contains above nodes. once you add above nodes to existing schema.xml then generate the new schema.xml from Sitecore(Control Panel->Indexing).
- Restart your Solr instance and try to rebuild the Index from Sitecore.
- Above steps resolve the issue for me. Hope it will help you as well.

Check [this](https://github.com/jerrong/Sitecore-Item-Buckets/blob/master/src/ItemBucket.Kernel/Kernel/Search/SOLR/schema.xml) for you reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Castle Windsor from NuGet by running this command in Visual Studio:

```
Install-Package Castle.Windsor -version 3.1.0
```

You’ll need to set up the IOC container in your global.asax. Edit your application’s global.asax as follows,

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorApplication" %>
```

Now, problem get resolve.

Regrads,
Piushpendra